# firebaseui not rendering login html

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

i am simply using the firebase ui email/password solution, and when it initializes, the main div (using `#firebaseui-auth-container` from the docs as the example), is populated with the needed markup, but the `ul. firebaseui-idp-list` element is empty, and there are no errors to troubleshoot. both `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider. PROVIDER_ID`, & `EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD` both return `password`

i am not sure where to go from here, except looking through the firebaseui source

```
uiConfig = {
  signInOptions: {
    forceSameDevice: false,
    provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    requireDisplayName: false,
    signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD
  }
};
ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

Comment: As far as I know `signInOptions` is an array of strings or objects, so `signInOptions: { {
    forceSameDevice: false,
    provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    requireDisplayName: false,
    signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD
  }]`

Answer (score 0):

`signInOptions` is an array of strings/objects. ty Frank van Puffelen

```
uiConfig = {
  signInOptions: [{
    forceSameDevice: false,
    provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    requireDisplayName: false,
    signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD
  }]
};
```